# Add new item to List object C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add new object to a list:
My code:

```
List<geo_tag> abc = new List<geo_tag>();
abc.Add(new geo_tag() { latitude = 111, longitude = 122, unit = "SSS" });
```

When run, it gets error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected at line 2.

Using .Net 2.0

Comment: I believe .NET 2.0 did not support inline object initialization. You need to use later version of .NET and C# or create an object of `geo_tag` separately and then add it the list.

Comment: Are you sure you are using .net 2 (2005) ?  And if so, why?

Answer (score 14):

The object initializer syntax you are using came with C# 3.0. For 2.0 you have to use

```
List<geo_tag> abc = new List<geo_tag>();
geo_tag tag = new geo_tag();
tag.latitude = 111;
tag.longitude = 122;
tag.unit = "SSS";
abc.Add(tag);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try This

```
List<geo_tag> abc = new List<geo_tag>();

geo_tag Model= new geo_tag();
Model.latitude =111;
Model.longitude =122;
Model.unit ="SSS";

abc.Add(Model);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
List<geo_tag> abc = new List<geo_tag>();
abc.Add(new geo_tag { latitude = 111, longitude = 122, unit = "SSS" });
```

geo_tag() Redundant ()

Comment: Can you please add more explaining words to your code?

Answer (score 3):

```
class Program{
public static void Main(string[] args){
    //add object in list.
    List<Geo> geo = new List<Geo> {
                new Geo { Latitude=111,Longitude=222,Unit="jjj"},
                new Geo { Latitude = 112, Longitude = 223, Unit = "nnn" },
                new Geo { Latitude = 113, Longitude = 224, Unit = "kkk" }
            };

    //looping for print list data in console.
    foreach (var s in geo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s.Latitude);
    }
    
    Console.ReadLine();
}
public class Geo
{
    public int Latitude { get; set; }
    public int Longitude { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
}}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this for example?

```
       List<geo_tag> abc = new List<geo_tag> {};
        abc.Add(new geo_tag(11, 112, "SSS"));


  public class geo_tag
{
    public int latitude { get; set; }
    public int longitude { get; set; }
    public string unit { get; set; }

    public geo_tag()
    {
    }
    public geo_tag(int latitude, int longitude, string unit)
    {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.unit = unit;
    }
}
```

Comment: We don´t really like code-only answers. Explain what the idea is and how to use it.

Comment: @HimBromBeere yes ı'know. :)

Comment: There´s still not really an explanation or anything *meaningul*.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new object "class" and add items to it by tow ways:

```
private class Employee
{
    public int _id { get; set; }
    public string _Name { get; set; }
}

var EmpList = new List<Employee>();


EmpList.Add(new Employee { _id=1, _Name = "ahmed" }); 
// or
Employee Emp = new Employee();
Emp._id = 2;
Emp._Name = " Hany Samy";
EmpList.Add(Emp);
```

Answer (score -1):

Creating new object of Geo and feeding the data at the time of initialization

```
  List<Geo> geo = new List<Geo> {
                    new Geo { Latitude=111,Longitude=222,Unit="jjj"},
                    new Geo { Latitude = 112, Longitude = 223, Unit = "nnn" },
                    new Geo { Latitude = 113, Longitude = 224, Unit = "kkk" }
                };
```

Comment: Why is this supposed to help?